# Wordpress - getting media library events

Tags: jquery, wordpress, events, media-library

I'm developing a gallery and this is the JS code for the media library:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

var custom_uploader;

jQuery('#upload_image_button').click(function(e) {

    //forbid default behaviour of the event
    e.preventDefault();

    //If the uploader object has already been created, reopen the dialog
    if (custom_uploader) {
        custom_uploader.open();
        return;
    }

    //Extend the wp.media object to create the window
    custom_uploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
        title: 'Choose Image',
        button: {
            text: 'Choose Image'
        },
        multiple: false
    });

    //When a file is selected, grab the URL and set it as the text field's value
    custom_uploader.on('select', function() {
        // Get media attachment details from the frame state
        attachment = custom_uploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
        jQuery('#upload_image').val(attachment.url);
    });

    //Open the uploader dialog
    custom_uploader.open();

   });
});
```

Now I need to get the image ID to arrange images from the media library which will take part on the gallery using PHP so I thought an AJAX/JSON call should be good to pass data from the media window created with wp.media after the user clicks on "Choose image".

How can I get this event?
I cant' find a list of events associated to wp.media but in the code above there's:

```
custom_uploader.on('select', function() {...}
```

so I think there could be a sort of `custom_uploader.on('buttonclick' function(){...}`, isn't it?

Otherwise how can I accomplish it?

Thank you!

Comment: Want to know what's the event to use with "custom_uploader.on( 'the-event-to-use', function(){...})" to get the click of the user on "Choose image" after it's chosen.

Comment: Ah. Thanks. Really, the problem is that the wordpress codex doesn't speak about wp.media exhaustively so it  gives me headache. Cant' find a proper API about that.